# How to summarize with two functions using with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to summarize this data set as an example and I'm trying to use multiple functions `n()` & `mean()`. How can I combine both in the same workflow?

Here is a toy dataset that mirrors my larger data:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(group_var = c(70, 72, 73, 70, 70, 71, 70, 71, 
                                   71, 70), var1_scr = c(50.5, 25.75, 50.5, 50.5, 50.5, 50.5, 75.25, 
                                                         75.25, 50.5, 75.25), var2_scr = c(50.5, 50.5, NA, 75.25, 50.5, 
                                                                                           50.5, 75.25, 75.25, 100, 75.25), var3_scr = c(NA, NA, 75.25, 
                                                                                                                                         NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                          "tbl", "data.frame"))
df
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>    group_var var1_scr var2_scr var3_scr
#>        <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1        70     50.5     50.5     NA  
#>  2        72     25.8     50.5     NA  
#>  3        73     50.5     NA       75.2
#>  4        70     50.5     75.2     NA  
#>  5        70     50.5     50.5     NA  
#>  6        71     50.5     50.5     NA  
#>  7        70     75.2     75.2     NA  
#>  8        71     75.2     75.2     NA  
#>  9        71     50.5    100       NA  
#> 10        70     75.2     75.2     NA

# summarize the scores
df %>%  group_by(group_var) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(ends_with("_scr")), funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))

#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   group_var var1_scr var2_scr var3_scr
#>       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1        70     60.4     65.4    NaN  
#> 2        71     58.8     75.2    NaN  
#> 3        72     25.8     50.5    NaN  
#> 4        73     50.5    NaN       75.2

# count all the oberservations
df %>%  group_by(group_var) %>% 
  summarise(obs = n())
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   group_var   obs
#>       <dbl> <int>
#> 1        70     5
#> 2        71     3
#> 3        72     1
#> 4        73     1

# my goal is to produce this dataset but using the mutate_at function
df %>%  group_by(group_var) %>% 
  summarise(var1_scr = mean(var1_scr), 
            var2_scr = mean(var2_scr),
            var3_scr = mean(var3_scr), 
            obs = n())
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   group_var var1_scr var2_scr var3_scr   obs
#>       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <int>
#> 1        70     60.4     65.4     NA       5
#> 2        71     58.8     75.2     NA       3
#> 3        72     25.8     50.5     NA       1
#> 4        73     50.5     NA       75.2     1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An option is to add the 'n' also in the grouping variable after grouping by 'group_var' and then do the `summarise_at`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
     group_by(group_var)  %>%
     group_by(obs = n(), add = TRUE) %>%
     summarise_at(vars(ends_with("_scr")), list(~mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   group_var [4]
#  group_var   obs var1_scr var2_scr var3_scr
#      <dbl> <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1        70     5     60.4     65.4    NaN  
#2        71     3     58.8     75.2    NaN  
#3        72     1     25.8     50.5    NaN  
#4        73     1     50.5    NaN       75.2
```

---

Another option is to create the frequency column with `mutate`, and get the `mean` by including that also in the `summarise_at` (e.g. `mean(rep(3, 5))` -> 3)

```
df %>% 
     group_by(group_var)  %>%
     mutate(obs = n()) %>%
     summarise_at(vars(ends_with("_scr"), obs), list(~mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
# A tibble: 4 x 5
#  group_var var1_scr var2_scr var3_scr   obs
#      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
#1        70     60.4     65.4    NaN       5
#2        71     58.8     75.2    NaN       3
#3        72     25.8     50.5    NaN       1
#4        73     50.5    NaN       75.2     1
```

NOTE: Both of these provide one column for the 'obs'

---

Here, the OP's expected output is a summarised output for which `summarise/summarise_at/summarise_all/summarise_if` are efficient.  However, if we need to use `mutate_at` (only for demonstration)

```
df %>% 
     group_by(group_var)  %>%
     mutate(obs = n()) %>%
     mutate_at(vars(ends_with("_scr"), obs), list(~mean(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
     distinct_at(vars(group_var, ends_with("_scr"), obs))
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   group_var [4]
#  group_var var1_scr var2_scr var3_scr   obs
#      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
#1        70     60.4     65.4    NaN       5
#2        72     25.8     50.5    NaN       1
#3        73     50.5    NaN       75.2     1
#4        71     58.8     75.2    NaN       3
```

Comment: Please ignore the `mutate_at` statement I meant `summarize_at`. Your answer is just what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

If you need the two function in the same call, we can do

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  group_by(group_var) %>% 
        summarise_at(vars(ends_with("_scr")), list(m=~mean(., na.rm = TRUE), n=~n()))

# A tibble: 4 x 7
   group_var var1_scr_m var2_scr_m var3_scr_m var1_scr_n var2_scr_n var3_scr_n
       <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <int>      <int>      <int>
1        70       60.4       65.4      NaN            5          5          5
2        71       58.8       75.2      NaN            3          3          3
3        72       25.8       50.5      NaN            1          1          1
4        73       50.5      NaN         75.2          1          1          1
```

Consider the OP note: *my goal is to produce this dataset but using the mutate_at function*

```
 df %>% group_by(group_var) %>% 
        mutate_at(vars(ends_with("_scr")), list(m=~mean(., na.rm = TRUE), n=~n())) %>% 
        slice(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I didn't know how to incorporate lists into the `summarise_at` function.